What is the purpose of the control voltage pin and reference voltage pin in an OCXO?
What is the control voltage pin and reference voltage pin in AOCJY3-100.000MHZ-E-SW OCXO?. In the datasheet, they didn't define the purpose of each pin. There are no such pins in clocks from other manufacturers, maybe this is unique to abracon.
Any idea what this could be?


Just a guess: if you want the OCXO to use internal feedback to stabilize frequency, you feed reference voltage to control voltage pin. If you want to provide external feedback, you provide that to control voltage pin.

The datasheet has Electrical Frequency Adjustment in the table of Standard Specifications:



Note #4: When Vdd=12.0V, Control Voltage Range is 0.0V to 5.0V and therefore, the Center Control Voltage is (2.50V±0.50V)

Which I understand to mean that the Control Voltage applied to pin 3 allows the frequency to be adjusted over the range of ±0.700 ppm.
The AOCJY OCXO APPLICATION NOTE shows some example connections between the Reference output and Control input, albeit the pin numbers shown in the AOCJY application note differ from those in the AOCJY3 datasheet:

AOCJY devices also provide a Regulated DC output on pin # 2 (Vref ). The value of this voltage is dependent upon the Supply Voltage bias. For instance, for Vdd = 5.0V; the Vref value will be +4.50V ±0.2V. Similarly for Vdd = 3.3V; the Vref value will be +2.80V ±0.2V.


